# Shell Execute function from win32api module is not working under Apache2.2 service

Tags: apache, python-2.7, winapi, apache2.2, pywin

The code:

```
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", "D:/prints/2.pdf" , None,  ".",  0)
```

The above code is working fine under Django server. But it is not working under apache2.2

what to do please help.

Comment: Various failure modes. Step 1 is to do some debugging. You might need to learn how to do that. For a start ShellExecuteEx is needed for sane error checking. So to begin with, use that function and check for errors as described in the docs.

Comment: i have written the code in try excpet block but still it is coming in try block but no error is displaying

Comment: Don't guess at how errors are handled. Read the documentation. This is not a Python function. It won't throw exceptions. It's a Win32 function. Read the docs on MSDN. And don't use `ShellExecute` since it cannot report errors properly. Use `ShellExecuteEx`.

Comment: I have just gone through it there it returned like "If the function succeeds, it returns a value greater than 32. If the function fails, it returns an error value that indicates the cause of the failure." .  so now i am getting 42 the return value is greater than 32 means it is success , but i am not getting any print

Comment: I still can't agree with you using ShellExecute. All the same, what's different about the execution environments?

Comment: I am not much ware of these win32api, could you give me suggestion of how to excute the above command by uising ShellExecuteEx

Comment: What's different about the execution environments?